# Call fragment method from activity but view is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am checking internet connection in my main activity.If connection is lost,I want to show reconnecting message in fragment.Example:If I run following code in main activity my app is crashing.

```
ConversationFragment conv1 = new ConversationFragment();
conv1.showReconnecting();
```

And this is the `showReconnecting` method in fragment:

```
public void showReconnecting() {
    final RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.reconnecting);
    rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I know why my app is crashing because `rootView` is setting in `onCreateView` and when I call this method from activity `rootView` is returning null.

What can I do for resolve this problem ?

Comment: What is your rootView? Do you want your Fragment to show above the Activity, like a dialog or to fill the whole screen, like a second Activity?

Comment: No.Example:I am showing a chat fragment meanwhile main activity is checking internet connection then internet connection is lost.Main activity should show a "Reconnecting" message in chat fragment.

Comment: Then, a simple dialog would do the job well.

Comment: What you mean with dialog ? Toast ?

Comment: A ProgressDialog. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you want to do, a simple `ProgressDialog` will do the job. You can lauch it from your `ChatFragment`, like this:

First, declare it on your Fragment:

```
private ProgressDialog connectiongProgressDialog;
```

Then, when you want to show it, use:

```
connectiongProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "My title", "Reconnecting");
```

When you want to dismiss it, use:

```
if (connectiongProgressDialog != null){
    connectiongProgressDialog .dismiss();
}
```

It will display a simple dialog with the message you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Assuming reconnecting view is in fragment and your fragment is visible on screen),

```
public void showReconnecting() {
    if (conv1 != null && conv1.getView()!=null) {
        final RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)conv1.getView().findViewById(R.id.reconnecting);
        rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

If conv1 is not available then please make it class variable.

Comment: Yes,try this in MainActivity

Comment: I tried it but still nullpointerexception for final RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)conv1.getView().findViewById(R.id.reconnecting);

Comment: where is your reconnecting view? In fragment or in activity?

Comment: reconnecting view is in fragment

Comment: see edited answer, just added a null check when fragment is not added if it is added it will work fine. See, if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62974/discussion-between-chirag-jain-and-serkay-sariman).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just looking at this and your explanation, I would think you can't call methods relating to a view (such as a fragment) without creating said fragment. An option, if the fragment is only used for showing the reconnecting, would be just to put some code in the activity and use a Toast.makeText(....).show();
which notifies the user that you are attempting to reconnect. So instead of `conv1.showReconnecting();` maybe rather put, `Toast.makeText(context,"Reconnecting", Toast.LONG).show();` and then do the necessary background work in an AsyncTask.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I want to place reconnecting only fragment.Toasts can see from every fragment.